# How to expand Word header and footer via C# word interop

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, interop, office-interop

When bulk editing images in the header and footer of word documents via word interop it works perfectly well for most documents. If however the header and footer of a document are collapsed, word crashes.

Now to **my question**: Can you expand the header/footer section automatically via word interop or do you know of another way to work around this problem?

Additional info:

When expanding the header/footer section manually and saving the document it works again, but that's no reasonable option because there are many documents to edit.

Collapsed header (doesn't work):
[image: screenshot of the collapsed header (doesn't work)]

Expanded header (works):
[image: screenshot of the expanded header (works)]

The Word error information:
[image: screenshot of the word error information]

The code I'm using for editing header images:

```
foreach (Section section in currentDocument.Sections)
{
    HeadersFooters headerFooters = section.Headers;
    foreach (HeaderFooter headerFooter in headerFooters)
    {
        InlineShapes inlineShapes = headerFooter.Range.InlineShapes;
        foreach (InlineShape shape in inlineShapes)
        {
            if (shape.Type != WdInlineShapeType.wdInlineShapePicture)
                continue;
            //[...]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to turn the full page display on/off:

```
Word.View vw = currentDocument.ActiveWindow.View;
if (vw.DisplayPageBoundaries == false) 
{
   vw.DisplayPageBoundaries = true;
}
```